# Issue with django URLconfig not finding URL patterns that I've set

Tags: python, django, http, url

I've been testing the waters with Django and getting myself more familiar with web development and I ran into an issue that I need some outside help for. My localhost is showing:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/blog/about
Using the URLconf defined in movie_log.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
The current path, blog/about, didn't match any of these.
```

my project urls.py file reads as

```
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

my urls.py file from the blog folder reads is

```
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="blog-home"),
    path('about/', views.about, name="blog-about"),
]
```

and finally the views.py file in the same "blog" folder is

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home(request):
    return HttpResponse('<h1>Blog Home</h1>')


def about(request):
    return HttpResponse('<h1>Blog About</h1>')
```

is there something im missing?

Comment: Did you add `blog` to the `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: In the settings.py file under INSTALLED_APPS check whether you have mentioned your app name

Comment: Please show the layout of the files in your project, including the project `urls.py`. Make sure you have saved any changes to your files and restarted `manage.py runserver`.